# Angular directive for google Maps attribute lost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to create a simple directive to show a google map of a location stored into a mongo document.
I pass the coordinates as attributes but when I get them into the `attrs` parameter they disapears.

```
<div id="map" lat="{{ location.latitude }}" lng="{{ location.logitude }}" google-map></div>
```

The directive:

```
app.directive('googleMap', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        console.log(attrs); // Will show lat and lng properties with their corresponding values
        console.log(attrs.lat); // Will show nothing. (!?)

        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.lat, attrs.lng), // It will systematically center to the coordinates 0,0

  ...
```

So, the questions are, why I cannot access the `attrs` property ? And how can I get them ?
Thanks.

Comment: can you put sample code into a jsfiddle? it'd help me answer your question.

Comment: Sometimes, Lat and lng values are stored as functions. try to console.log(attrs.lat())

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I finally solved this by using angular-google-maps dependency instead of making my own directive.